# What should we do with [[this]-keyword]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tag [this-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-keyword) refers to a keyword named `this` in many object-oriented languages that (normally) refers to the receiver object. It has no tag wiki.

There is a tag named [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this) as well. Its tag wiki excerpt clearly states that it is about the keyword `this` as well:

> Keyword that refers to the current class instance or object in many object-oriented programming languages.

Furthermore, there exists a similar tag named [this-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-pointer). That tag seems to be about the same concept but for C++ ([105](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-pointer%20c%2b%2b)/[134](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-pointer) [this-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-pointer) are also tagged with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) while there are [32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-pointer+this) questions with [this-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-pointer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this) but [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-pointer+this-keyword) question tagged with both [this-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-keyword) and [this-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-pointer)). The tag wiki excerpt states:

> The "this" pointer is a compiler-generated pointer during a function call that points to the object upon which that function gets called.

Should we copy the tag wiki of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this) to [this-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-keyword) and synonymize them or should we otherwise disambiguate them?

Should we do the same with [this-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-pointer)? Are there other tags about the same concept that should be treated similarly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> should we otherwise unambiguate them?

There doesn't seem to be a problem with the usage of either tags. Both are consistently used for questions about how `this` functions in various object-oriented languages.

> Should we copy the tag wiki of this to this-keyword and synonymize them

The [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this) and [this-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-keyword) definitely should be synonymized. They refer to the same concept, and thus are prime candidates for synonymization. While there aren't that many questions (37 ATTOW, many of them about ECMAScript's `this` keyword), and a simple retag would solve the problem, it refers to a common enough term to justify adding [this-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-keyword) as a synonym to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this) (as the latter is a much more established tag).

> Should we do the same with [this-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this-pointer)?

I would avoid touching that tag. It refers to a concept specific to C++ and thus serves the primary purpose of tags: to help connect questions and experts in the field. But its usage does need a [little cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bthis-pointer%5D+-%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3), as there are quite a few questions on ECMAScript (sic!) and C# (not an SME here, so can't comment if this is a case of misuse).

Comment: Merged [this-keyword] into [this] (27 questions retagged so it was a poor sub-tag). I tend to agree [this-pointer] doesn't seem like the same thing